# Why in the stellar network the price for 1 transaction and 1 operation is not equal to the price for 1 transaction and 100 operation?

Tags: transactions, operations

*Why in the stellar network the price for 1 transaction and 1 operation is not equal to the price for 1 transaction and 100 operation?*

In 2 case the network load will be less? (if 100 transactions with 1 operation are made)

Mine needs to be stimulated (at the cost of transaction) to use more operations in 1 transaction, rather than transactions

Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of bundling operations in a single transaction is not to save resources but to execute them in a "all fail if one fails" fashion which allows stellar smart contracts in the first place.

There is currently a limit of 50 transactions per ledger but as far as I know that is also supposed to be changed to a maximum operations per ledger limit in future.

Comment: Did not quite understand what you want to say ...

Comment: now I understand))
What if in these 100 operations at least one does not work, then all 100 will be sent again.
But all the same it will turn out 2 requests, 1 we process erroneous operations (we delete) and we send again, total 2 requests))

Answer (score 0):

Fees are intended to add a cost for using the network as a spam prevention measure. Since you can submit 1 payment per operation, operations have a fee. 100 transactions with 1 operation will cost the same as 1 transaction with 100 operations.

See the [docs on fees](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html) for more information.

> The Stellar network requires small fees on transactions and minimum balances on accounts in order to prevent people from overwhelming the network and to aid in prioritization.
>
> The fee for a transaction is the number of operations the transaction contains multiplied by the base fee, which is 100 stroops (0.00001 XLM).

Comment: Yes, I know why transaction fees are entered. 
"100 transactions with 1 operation will cost the same as 1 transaction with 100 operations." - 
as far as I understand it is not the same for network resources

Comment: To my knowledge it's the number of operations that determines how expensive it is for the network to process, if you have information suggesting otherwise I'd love to read it.

Comment: I also have no information, but I can locally do a test on the stellar private network (send 10,000 transactions with 1 operation, and send 100 transactions with 100 operations)
 and see the use of local server resources